# Changing Minecraft's item rarity color

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know how to change item's name color, but i want to override minecraft's default rarity colors. Like rare items have cyan color and i want it to be dark-red.

Comment: No way that I know of to exactly do what your asking about, but you can change the language file in a resource pack to change a specific items default display string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, you could use a datapack to detect the item in the player's mainhand (since that is the only time you will see the name's color) and modify the item data to change the name color.

This would require a list of all the items and depending on the version of Minecraft you are playing, you may have to use a difficult method to modify the player's mainhand item data; fortunately, in 1.17 this becomes very simple with the new `/item` command.